# XML security in data transfer from one application to another application

Tags: xml

I have seen in the past Once an XML is Valid and Well-Formed, gets encrypted before transferring via network to a different web application.

Base64 encoding in Java is one of them.

Are there different encoding/encrypting algorithms to make XML documents secure? Please let me know.

Comment: Encryption and encoding are *very* different things

Comment: Encode the XML and then encrypt it before transferring? is it right?